# is wordpress stores Role Id in WP database?

Tags: database, user-roles

i want to extend default roles in my code. and i want to use role id of WordPress roles.

i find out role names are stored in 'wp_options' table under key name 'wp_user_roles'.

but i am not able to find out role id please tell me where it stored?

Answer (score 3):

The "ID" of the role is the array key in `wp_user_roles`.

The value of `wp_user_roles` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [administrator] => Array
        (
            [name] => Administrator
            [capabilities] => Array

        )

    [author] => Array
        (
            [name] => Author
            [capabilities] => Array
        )
)
```

In that example, `administrator` and `author` are the closest thing there is to a "role ID".

Comment: you mean to say, i have to use slug, there is no int id stored in db.

Comment: Yes, there's no ID.